# tabpy connections issue [tableau & python]

Tags: python, tableau-api

I'm getting this problem while using tabpy. I'm using the sample - supterstore datasets, and I want to cluster the sub-category using the sum([Profit]) and sum([Sales]), but it returns the error:

> ValueError : n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=2.

Here's my script:

```
SCRIPT_str("
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
    tmp=[]
    for i in range(len(_arg1)):   
        tmp.extend([[_arg1[i],_arg2[i]]]) 
    KMmodel = kmeans.fit(tmp)
    labels = KMmodel.labels_
    return labels", 
sum([Profit]),sum([Sales]))
```

Comment: Rather than `tmp = []` and two following lines, did you maybe want `tmp = zip(_arg1, _arg2)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the N-clusters option to 1 and check

Comment: When is it helpful to have KMeans "decide" into which of k=1 clusters each example should be clustered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy column_stack and compute using sub-category.

```
SCRIPT_INT(
"
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
X = np.column_stack([_arg1,_arg2])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)
return kmeans.labels_.tolist()
", SUM([Profit]),SUM([Sales])
)
```

Here is my results:[image]